# wxpython or pygame?

Tags: python, wxpython, pygame

I am attempting to make a virtual playbook application for football teams and coaches. I am stuck on trying to decide if I should use wxpython and pygame or just wxpython. I want it to be just an X's and O's type. Is there anyway I could just use wxpython to make a drag and drop for the X's and O's and also can I draw lines in just wxpython? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Both are simple and fun to use libraries.. i personally recommend pygame as i have some experience in it and rather like it. It is a fully fledged 2D game api based on SDL while wxpython is more suited towards dialogs, guis and controls or rather software programming. I say go with pygame, please make sure to read and reference the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) thoroughly and here are some good [tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=20) to get you started..

Yes you can draw lines in wxpython but it is a bit more difficult to use for game purposes.